# What is the use of creating a domain model?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, oop

I have two classes:

```
Order
int OrderId
string OrderName
List<Product> Products

Product
int ProductId
string ProductName
Order Order
```

I have two tables: Order, Product in MS SQL DB

I want to show on the UI a list of orders in a combo box.  On selection of an order, a list of products is shown.

I have a stored procedure which returns a table of products for the order: GetProductByOrderId
I have a storderd procedure which returns a table of orders:
GetOrders

How would I map this table to the product class?

Would I do something like this:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = reader["Name"]
product.Order = new Order();
product.Order.Id = reader["OrderId"];
```

Or should I change my class model so for the Product class, I will only have OrderId and I will map my classes models to look identical to my database tables?

When I get the Order objects, should I create

```
Order order = new Order();
order.Products = new List<Product>()
```

even though I don't need to get the products then what's the point of having it in the list?

I don't see the benefits of having a proper domain model when all I am doing is setting few properties of the related entities?

P.S. Original application has over 65 tables involved.

Comment: Personally, i'd prefer `product.Order = Order.FindOrCreateByID(reader["OrderId"]);` and/or `order.AddProduct(product);`.  But that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to if you don't believe it is necessary - perhaps the overheads outweigh the benefit.

Your question is about navigation of the object model. So when you select your order how are you going to get the list of products - cycle through each product to check its order id?
Depending on you complete application it may be better to use the order.products one-to-many.

Isn't this more understandable also? When you model is large and you hand over to others - wouldn't this make it more maintainable?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have minimal needs there's no reason that you "have" to set up your domain model in that way. Normally I set up my relationships in the database, and then import into the Entity Data Model as it is setup in SQL Server. One of the purposes this serves is that I can easily build hierarchical lists based on my data. And builds a visual representation for myself and other developers on how the data should interact.

So if you only have two tables, and aren't worried about it, there's no reason that you have to.